# Is there any difference if I use cropped objects or full frames for training a cascade classifier?

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, classification, cascade-classifier

Can I use cropped objects from full frames as training dataset for a cascade classifier (LBP or HAAR)?

I know that I have to use full frames with annotations when retraining a neural net (Tensorflow, YOLO and so on)

But do I need it for a cascade classifier? Or cropped images are ok?

It seems I can do it because we have positive and negative images

So it should be ok to crop objects from positive images

E.g.

[image]

or

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question **Can I use cropped objects from full frames as a training dataset for a cascade classifier (LBP or HAAR)** is yes. It depends on your model architecture, your aims and system compatibility. For training, we normally crop target objects from a whole image and feed into the model.

The answer to your this question **I know that I have to use full frames with annotations when retraining a neural net (Tensorflow, YOLO and so on)** It depends. What is your ROI size? You can resize your ROIs according to your architecture or, You can crop target objects from ROIs. It is completely up to you.

But do I need it for a cascade classifier? Or cropped images are ok?-Answer is both are okay. Choose based on your model architecture, training time, system configuration, and obviously training performance.

Comment: Can you give an example of how you would configure your ROI size given his image and  object?